# Program printing out unnecessary duplicates of wanted results

Tags: java

I created a Java program which takes user input as an integer array and prints any duplicate values in that array along with their indices. For example, user enters 5 to be the array size, then enters 5 numbers, such as 1, 1, 1, 1, and 1. 
Program should print: 
Duplicate number: 1
Duplicate number's index: 1
Duplicate number: 1
Duplicate number's index: 2
Duplicate number: 1
Duplicate number's index: 3
Duplicate number: 1
Duplicate number's index: 4

However, program prints: 
Duplicate number: 1
Duplicate number's index: 1
Duplicate number: 1
Duplicate number's index: 2
Duplicate number: 1
Duplicate number's index: 3
Duplicate number: 1
Duplicate number's index: 4
Duplicate number: 1
Duplicate number's index: 2
Duplicate number: 1
Duplicate number's index: 3
Duplicate number: 1
Duplicate number's index: 4
Duplicate number: 1
Duplicate number's index: 3
Duplicate number: 1
Duplicate number's index: 4
Duplicate number: 1
Duplicate number's index: 4

I tried to debug the program and the conclusion I got was that because the print result is within loops, as long as the loops run and meet certain conditions, there will be multiple prints. However, I cannot find ways to make code different so only the correct number of results is printed. I tried to adjust code: insert break and continue, put the print.out statements outside the loops, but nothing works.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); int i, j; 
    System.out.println("This program lets you enter an array of numbers, and then tells you if any of the numbers are duplices, and what the duplicates' indices are. \nPlease enter your desired array size: ");
    int arraySize = sc.nextInt(); 
    while (arraySize <= 0) { System.out.println(arraySize + " is not a valid number. \nPlease enter your desired array size: ");
       arraySize = sc.nextInt(); continue;}  
       int[] arrayList = new int[arraySize];    
    System.out.println("Please enter your array values: ");         
    for (i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        arrayList[i] = sc.nextInt();  }

    for (i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++)  {
        for (j = i + 1; j < arrayList.length; j++)  {            

            if (i!=j && arrayList[i] == arrayList[j])   {
                System.out.println("Duplicate number: " + arrayList[i]);                                  
                System.out.println("Duplicate number's index: " + j); } 
            else if (i!=j && arrayList[i] != arrayList[j])  {System.out.println("There are no duplicates");  }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: If you're checking each number, then every duplicate will, naturally, also have a duplicate. So for index `0`, it has a duplicate at index `1`. When your loop gets to index `1`, it finds a duplicate in index `0`. Thus, printing twice.

Comment: @zephyr Are you sure about that?  It appears that the inner loop is indexed to be one more than the outer loop. Perhaps I am misunderstanding.

Comment: Eh, I didn't read it all that closely. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is finding the duplicates of a duplicate.  Take 1,1,1.  First you find two duplicates of 1, index 0 at index 1, and 2.  Then you find a duplicate of 1, index 1 at index 2.  There are several solutions.

1. Keep track of the encountered duplicates.  If one has already been processed by the outer loop, then don't process it again. You can do this by having a separate `list` to house the found duplicates and use the `contains` method to check if it exists.
2. Sort the list and then look for sequences of duplicates.  That changes the position so it may not be what you want.
3. Remove the duplicate as you find it.  This also changes the position so it may not be what you want either.  I also adds some additional complexity.

You also have a different problem.

1. When duplicates are encountered, you also print out that no duplicates are found too which seem contradictory To solve this, use a `boolean` flag and set to false if duplicates are found and use that to print the message when exiting the loops.
2. Since you start you inner loop one more than the outer loop (i.e. `j = 0 and i = j+1`) they can never be the same.  So you don't need the `(i!=j)` test. Also, the termination of your outer loop should be `arrayList.length-1`.

Comment: what you're saying makes sense, thank you for showing what the root of the problem is. For solution #1, are you suggesting that I create a separate list array to house any found duplicates, then use contains method to check the array if the duplicate exists and then exclude the duplicate from being processed again?

Comment: Exactly!.  But you are using explicit arrays.  I was thinking of using something like ArrayList<Integer>.  You wouldn't have to change your arrays to ArrayList.  But using it for the duplicates is easy because it grows dynamically and it has the contains method.

Comment: where within the code should I put the Boolean condition? I tried putting it in multiple places where it would make sense to put it, but it still prints "there are no duplicates" even if there are duplicates.

Comment: I tweaked code based on your suggestions, and it works fine as far as "there is duplicate x and it is at index y," however...now it prints "there are no duplicates" even if there are duplicates. I put boolean flag as you suggested, but no correct result.    for (i = 0; i < arrayList.length-1; i++)  {
for (j = i+1; j < arrayList.length; j++)  {  if (arrayList[i] == arrayList[j])  {System.out.println("Duplicate number: " + arrayList[i]);                                
System.out.println("Duplicate number's index: " + j); break;}       }  }   {System.out.println("There are no duplicates.");}

Comment: Before you enter your loops, set the `boolean` `nodups` to `true`.  Then when you find a single duplicate, set it to `false` (this may occur multiple times and be redundant).  Then when you exit both loops, use that value to print if there were duplicates.  So if there were duplicates. you would print them.  If there weren't, the value would never be set to `false` and you would print there weren't any.